# Some phrases to express couples who match with each other

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In order to say two people as a couple, are perfect for each other, what phrases would you recommend to use as a complement? Something to express they are perfect match to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple that "has good chemistry" gets along really well.

A "compatible" couple fit together really well.

A "power couple" are a couple that together, can do anything.

**Edit for asker's visual:**

A "cute" couple look good together.

A "good-looking" couple implies that the members of the couple are both independently attractive.  (You could also use "hot", " sexy" or "attractive" and it would have a similar meaning.)

A couple that is "equally attractive" have a similar level of attraction.  (Both members are attractive, or unattractive, etc.)

Comment: they are very cool. almost got my answer, but what if I want to express the compatibility visualy. I mean they are as much as handsome and beautiful  as eachother.

Comment: Edited to try and fit your request.

Answer (score 3):

Whether two words, one, or hyphenated, one’s “[soulmate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soul-mate)
” is “a person with whom one has a strong affinity, shared values and tastes, and often a romantic bond: 
I married my soul mate; you don't get much luckier than that.” (from Dictionary[dot]com)

(Edited, not to steal @Elian’s good answer, but merely to point out the close connection between his answer and mine and that if his deserves down-voting, so does mine):

> [The idea of soulmate is] more than about compatability … more than
>   just being suited to each other.  It’s as if you ‘**belong with each
>   other**,’ and always have, and know it from the instant you meet.

(from ‘[SoulMates](https://books.google.com/books?id=B3KOjJBJy8YC&pg=PT11&lpg=PT11&dq=%22belong+with+each+other%22+soulmate&source=bl&ots=dbWRaB89mq&sig=q0V6OkPqOF5ZtScOBnjZATDpHf4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI7eXDiaLMyAIVE_WACh3beQlP#v=onepage&q=%22belong%20with%20each%20other%22%20soulmate&f=false)’ via Google Books)

Answer (score 2):

I would say, they **belong with each other** or **they belong together**.

> *We use **belong with** when we think something or someone is a part of a group, there is a match. For example, it would be very romantic to
> think that two people belong with each other.*  [Two Min
> English](http://twominenglish.com/video/121-Belong_To_Belong_With_English_Grammar_Lesson.html)
>
> *Do they **belong together**? Well, what other woman would keep taking back
> J.R.? Maybe Mandy Winger, doubtedly Cally, but Sue Ellen and J.R. have
> a history together. Remember J.R. let Mandy Winger go. I think he was
> more in lust with her though. Cally was another in lust situation. It's
> just that Sue Ellen knows what J.R. is all about. Mandy never knew the
> real J.R., only the loving one. Cally also knew about the real J.R.,
> but she didn't go through hell like Sue Ellen did. J.R. and Sue Ellen
> were meant to be together. I would be surprised if there was a last
> and final Dallas that Sue Ellen and J.R. don't get back together
> again. I can see them getting married for a third time - as far
> fetched as that may sound. Anyway LOL to J.R. and Sue Ellen!* [Soap Chat](http://soapchat.net/index.php?threads/will-jr-and-sue-ellen-always-find-away-to-be-together.11285/)

Going along with the visual aspect, consider **they make a (very) nice couple**.

> *Mr. And Mrs.  Armstrong make a very nice couple and seem to be a perfect match for each other.*

Answer (score 1):

You may say that:

> - They are well/happily/perfectly matched,
> - They are good together,
> - It's a perfect casting,
> - Everyone says they make a good match,
> - They are meant for eachother,
> - They are getting along well.